# about dual space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Im reading a chapter talking about dual space in optimization by vector space. I have captured something confusing as follow[image: s]:

[image]

I have been confused by two sentenses that one is " The mapping φ:X -> X** defined by x** = φ(x) where < x* , x** > = < x , x* > is called a natural mapping of X into X** ", and the other is " this mapping is linear and, as shown in the preceding paragraph, is norm preserving(i.e., ||φ(x)|| = ||x||). " So how to prove that < x* , x** > = < x , x* >? and why this mapping is norm preserving? Besides, Im still confusing that the author talked about the second dual space without any space introduced. Namely, for example, if we talk about the dual of lp space that means we have had built the topic on lp space with lp norm. Since no space introduced, how could he use the symbol of "< , >", which means the inner product, to simplify f(αx1* + βx2*)?

Comment: To clarify all that, first you have to think about a more basic point: what is a dual space? Can you tell us that? Also: in this context, $<x,x^*>$ is not meant to indicate inner product because $x$ and $x^*$ **do not live in the same space** - $x$ is in the original space in $x^*$ is in its dual.

Comment: The author is talking about an abstract inner product space. The construction of the dual space holds for all inner product spaces. So, the $\langle,\rangle>$ refers to the abstract inner product. It is not given by a formula but rather is given axiomatically.

Comment: @SergioParreiras

Comment: Thanks for ur reply^_^. I have rechecked the definition of dual in this chapter, said that: " Let X be a normed linear vector space. The space of all bounded linear functionals on X is called the normed dual of X and is denoted X*. The norm of an element f belonging to X* is || f || = sup | f(x) | while || x || <= 1", is that right? @SergioParreiras

Comment: @Frank_W : Yes so $X^*$ is the space of all linear functions with domain in $X$, right? $<x,x^*>$ should be read as the value of the linear mapping $x^*$. That is $<x,x^*>=x^*(x)$. Now... Things get interesting because if you fix some $x$ in $X$ and let $x^*$ in $X^*$ vary, you get a linear functional defined in $X^*$. In this additional interpretation you have $<x,x^*>=x(x^*)$ but now $x$ should be thought as an element of $X^{**}$ since it is defining a linear functional in $X^*$. Does that help?

Comment: yes. I got a little understanding. However, how could u know that x(x*) will be linear? just because the < x , x* > is the notation that represents all linear mapping x* from x to scalar field? Can I write x(x*) with < x* , x > ? thank u @SergioParreiras

Comment: @Frank_W : We know x is defining a linear mapping in $X^**$ because we get paper and pencil and prove it: Pick any $x^*$ and $y^*$ linear mappings in $X$ -- that is points in $X^*$ -- and $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then $x(x^*)=x^*(x)$ and $x(y^*)=y^*(x)$. Also $a\cdot x^*+b\cdot y^*$ is also a linear mapping with domain in $X$ -- that is, it is also a point in $X^*$. And so $(a\cdot x^*+b\cdot y^*)(x)=a\cdot x^*(x)+by^*(x)=a\cdot x(x^*)+b\cdot x(y^*)$ so $x$ is a linear mapping with domain in $X^*$.

Comment: @SergioParreiras: that does make sense. By the way, < x , x* > is the same to < x* , x >, is that right? how to prove the norm preserving?

Comment: @Frank_W : yes we have that $<x,x^*>$ is the same as $<x^*,x>$ in our context. To show it is norm preserving you have to use the definition of the norm in these spaces. $|x^*|_{X^*}=\sup\limits_{x\in X: |x|_{X}\le 1} <x^*,x>$, $|x|_{X^{**}}=\sup\limits_{x^*\in X^*: |x^*|_{X^*}\le 1} <x^*,x>$. You need to prove that $|x|_X=|x|_{X^{**}}$. The following inequality may be useful $|<x^*,x>|\le |x^*|\cdot |x|_S$ where $S=X$ or $S=X^{**}$.

Comment: @SergioParreiras: Thank u very much. I will try it later on and if any problem have, i will post up here^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first line of the cited text says, $\langle x,g\rangle$ denotes the value $g(x)$ if $g\in X^*=\{X\to K$ linear maps$\}$ where $K$ is the base field. $X^*$ is called the dual space, and $X^{**}$ is the *second dual* space of $X$. The embedding $x\mapsto x^{**}$ is based on $x^{**}(g):=g(x)$. (This is the same as $\langle g,x^{**}\rangle=\langle x,g\rangle$ in the alternative notation introduced in the first line.)

Answer (score 0):

> So how to prove that < x* , x** > = < x , x* >? and why this mapping is norm preserving?

You don't prove the equality. So $x^{**} = \varphi(x)$, the mapping is defined as the solution of the equation

$$
\left\langle x^{**}, x^*\right\rangle = \left\langle x^{*}, x\right\rangle \;\;\; \forall x^*\in X^* \;\;\;\;\; (1)
$$

You first need to show that the map is well defined, namely for every $x \in X$ there's a unique $x^{**}$ solving $(1)$. Suppose indeed there's an $x\in X$ for which $(1)$ has two solution, namely $x_1^{**}$ and $x_2^{**}$ we have then

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\left\langle x_1^{**}, x^*\right\rangle = \left\langle x^{*}, x\right\rangle \\
\left\langle x_2^{**}, x^*\right\rangle = \left\langle x^{*}, x\right\rangle
\end{array}
\right. \;\; \forall x^* \in X^* \Rightarrow \left\langle x_1^{**}, x^*\right\rangle 
= \left\langle x_2^{**}, x^*\right\rangle \; \forall x^* \in X^* \\
\Rightarrow \left\langle x_1^{**}, x^*\right\rangle 
- \left\langle x_2^{**}, x^*\right\rangle = 0 \; \forall x^* \in X^* \Rightarrow \left\langle x_1^{**} - x_2^{**}, x^*\right\rangle \forall x^* \in X^*
 = 0 \\
\Rightarrow x_1^{**} - x_2^{**} = 0 \Rightarrow x_1^{**} = x_2^{**}
$$

This shows that $\varphi$ is well defined (I skipped the linearity but is trivial).

For the norm preserving you can use the Hahn Banach theorem.

> **Proposition** Let $X$ a n.v.s. and $x \in X$ then there's a $x^* \in X^*$ such that $\left\langle x^* , x \right\rangle = \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X$.

You can prove the proposition above as an exercise and observe moreover that such $x^*$ has unit norm.
Let me rewrite $(1)$ in terms of $\varphi$

$$
\left\langle \varphi(x), x^*\right\rangle = \left\langle x^{*}, x\right\rangle \;\;\; \forall x^*\in X^*
$$

Specifically needs to hold for an $x^*$ such that $\left\langle x^*,x\right\rangle = \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X$. For such $x^*$ we have

$$
\left\langle \varphi(x),x^* \right\rangle = \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \Rightarrow \left\lVert \varphi(x) \right\rVert_{X^{**}} \left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} \geq \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \Rightarrow \left\lVert \varphi(x) \right\rVert_{X^{**}} \geq \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \;\;\; (2)
$$

But we also have

$$
\left\lVert \varphi(x) \right\rVert_{X^{**}} = \sup_{\left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} = 1} | \left\langle \varphi(x),x^* \right\rangle | = \sup_{\left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} = 1} | \left\langle x^*, x \right\rangle | \leq \sup_{\left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} = 1} \left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X = \\ \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \sup_{\left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} = 1} \left\lVert x^* \right\rVert_{X^*} = \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \Rightarrow \left\lVert \varphi(x) \right\rVert_{X^{**}} \leq \left\lVert x \right\rVert_X \;\; (3)
$$

Combining (2) and (3) gives us the isometry.